# Modifying superscript color in authors \email

Tags: color, email

How can I modify the color of superscript (near author name) which refers to email? I would like to use \email for that. In the following example I would like the "*" symbol to be colored (both, the one on top of the page as well as the bottom one).

```
\documentclass[pre,aps,twocolumn,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}


\begin{document}

\title{My title}

\author{name surname}
\email{mymail@email.com}

\maketitle 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prepend `\color{<color>}` to `\frontmatter@thefootnote`.

```latex
\documentclass[pre,aps,twocolumn,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd\frontmatter@thefootnote{\color{red}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{My title}

\author{name surname}
\email{mymail@email.com}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Do you know by any chance how to do the same with \thanks?

Comment: @MLS Probably a similar trick works, but I'm not going to try without an example of code to play with. I never use `revtex` for my document, so I'm not expert with it. Classes have very different ideas of where `\thanks` should be placed.